# Access SQL STDEV resulting in #error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm attempting to calculate the standard deviation of a field in access via a query. Here is the formula I am using:

```
SELECT STDev(Answers.[Answer (#)]) AS 'Standard Deviation'
FROM Answers;
```

When the query is run I get #error as the answer. The query seems simple enough and I don't think my syntax is wrong. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It should read:

```
SELECT STDev(Answers.[Answer (#)]) AS [Standard Deviation]
FROM Answers;
```

To exclude/ignore *Null* values:

```
SELECT STDev(Nz(Answers.[Answer (#)], 0)) AS [Standard Deviation]
FROM Answers;
```

or:

```
SELECT STDev(Answers.[Answer (#)]) AS [Standard Deviation]
FROM Answers
WHERE Answers.[Answer (#)] Is Not Null;
```

Comment: Still getting #error for a result. The same formula works when replacing STDev with AVG, clueless on why I keep getting error.

Comment: Still getting #error as the answer. The first exclude/ ignore Null values query gave me a compile error in query expression.

Comment: Then something else is going. Create a table with a small sample and check with this.